# Dynamic higher order row-by-row product

Tags: r, dynamic, matrix

I have a question on the following issue:

Suppose I have some matrices

```
A1 <- matrix(runif(rowsA1*T), rowsA1, T)
…
AD <- matrix(runif(rowsAD*T), rowsAD, T)
```

The number of matrices is variable (but most certainly not too large).
Is there a way to perform the following more efficiently (but in a set-up that allows for a variable number of matrices):

```
f1 <- function(A1, A2, ..., AD) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(A1)) {
    for(j in 1:nrow(A2)) {
      ...
        for(d in 1:nrow(AD)) {
          ret[i,j,...,d] <- \sum_{t=1}^T (A1[i,t]*A2[j,t]*...*AD[d,t])
        }
      ...
    }
  }
ret
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Romain

---------------------------------- Edit with example ----------------------------------

```
 A1 <- |a b c|  A2 <- |j k l|  A3 <- |s t u|
       |d e f|        |m n o|        |v w x|
       |g h i|        |p q r|        |y z ä|
```

And I want for instance to get the following:

```
ret[1,1,1] <- a*j*s + b*k*t + c*l*u
ret[2,1,3] <- d*j*y + e*k*z + f*l*ä
```

Hopefully this makes my point clearer.

---------------------------------- Edit Nov. 26th, 2013 -------------------------------

Hi @flodel. I tried to implement your code, but there seems to be an issue once one has more than three matrices.

Suppose, I have the following matrices

```
A1 <- matrix(runif(4*3), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
A2 <- matrix(runif(3*3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
A3 <- matrix(runif(2*3), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
A4 <- matrix(runif(1*3), nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
```

and pluging them into your code

```
output.f1 <- f1(A1,A2,A3,A4)
```

provides the correct number of dimensions

```
dim(output)
# [1] 4 3 2 1
```

but the output is full of NAs

```
output.f1
# , , 1, 1

           # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 0.13534704   NA   NA
# [2,] 0.07360135   NA   NA
# [3,] 0.07360135   NA   NA
# [4,] 0.07360135   NA   NA

# , , 2, 1

     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Thanks for some help...

Best,
Romain

Comment: `A1, A2, ..., AD` have the same dimensions, for example, all have 3 rows and 4 columns?

Comment: The matrices `A1, A2, ..., AD` have the same number of columns, that's for sure. But the number of rows may be different (but not necessarily).

Comment: Please notice the correction of the formula. I spotted the error too late. Sorry for the invonvenience!

Comment: Can you make you example reproducible with 3 small matrix at least. It is not clear the desired output.

Comment: See my added example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. With a big `apply` loop, it might be slow with large matrices, but it will do the job as far as being general to any number of matrices without necessarily the same number of rows:

```
f1 <- function(...) {
  args    <- list(...)
  nrows   <- sapply(args, nrow)
  idx     <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(nrows, seq.int))
  get.row <- function(i, mat) mat[i, ]
  get.val <- function(i.vec) sum(Reduce(`*`, Map(get.row, i.vec, args)))
  idx$val <- apply(idx, 1, get.val)
  ret     <- array(NA, dim = nrows)
  ret[as.matrix(idx[, seq_along(args)])] <- idx$val
  ret
}
```

Example usage:

```
A1 <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
A2 <- matrix(1:9,  nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
A3 <- matrix(1:6,  nrow = 2, ncol = 3)

out <- f1(A1, A2, A3)
```

Check:

```
identical(out[3, 2, 1],
          sum(A1[3, ] * A2[2, ] * A3[1, ]))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: (If speed is still a concern, let me know, I have other ideas but little time to test them now...)

Comment: Thanks flodel for your solution. Indeed, this version shall work for my needs. But if you know a faster version, than I'd be glad to see that one.

Comment: Hi @flodel. Would you mind having a look at my example above. I guess that there's an issue with your solution... Thanks

Comment: Should be fixed now. There was a hardcoded `1:3` that should have been `seq_along(args)` so it can work with any number of arguments, not just three. If this answers your question, please consider voting and accepting it.